# IntelliJ/PyCharm only provides intellisense suggestions for definitions in same file

Tags: python, intellij-idea, pycharm, intellisense

I've been using WebStorm and IntelliJ for about 5 years combined but am new to Python.
I am used to intellisense providing suggestions that are not just constrained to things defined in the file or already imported.

I've downloaded PyCharm to see if it's a configuration issue, but it also does not work as desired. I have seen bug tickets on JetBrains' site with screenshots appearing to show intellisense working as I desire.

I've probably spent 3 hours in total trying to resolve this issue and am starting to doubt it's possible.

example directory structure:

```
root_directory (marked as "Sources Root")
-thing_to_import.py
-will_import.py
```

where thing_to_import.py is simply:

`A_THING = 'please work'`

Typing any portion of `A_THING` in will_import.py does not provide a suggestion to import the desired variable. "control + space" leads to a "No suggestions" popover.

Does something in Python prevent this sort of functionality from working, or am I having a configuration issue?

Comment: Try to call `Ctrl+Space` twice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `will_import.py` files needs to import the `thing_to_import.py` module even though they're in the same directory.

```
import thing_to_import
```

Comment: That's what I feared. Though, even that doesn't work most of the time. Occasionally I'll get a suggestion once typing what you have above, but not reliably.

Comment: @RyanDagg Case matters for PyCharm IntelliSense. And of course, the item must be accessible in the current scope.